# .NET 6 - Building solution at Docker conteiner taking a long time and consuming more than 16GB memory

Tags: .net, windows, docker, memory-leaks, proxy

I'm following this guide to build my .NET 6 application inside a docker container:

https://stackify.com/a-start-to-finish-guide-to-docker-for-net/

Using the following Dockerfile:

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/docker-guide.dll"]
```

I discovered it takes a long time and consumes a huge ammount of RAM memory.

I'm using Docker Desktop at Windows 11.

How can I build it correctly inside a docker container?

Answer (score -1):

After some time I found that it has something to do with the proxy being used at dotnet restore.

I added before dotnet restore:

```html
RUN export http_proxy=proxy:80
RUN export https_proxy=$http_proxy
```

And the problem was solved, now the building is working faster and with a reasonable ammount of RAM.