# running a self contained dotnet core app on a linux container gives error

Tags: .net, linux, docker

i'm trying to create a self-contained .net 7 console application and run it on a linux container manually.  to that end this is what i'm doing

1. publish the console application as a self contained using the following `dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained true /p:PublishTrimmed=true -o ./deploy`
2. run the following container `docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0-alpine`
3. copy the output of `step 1` into the container on `step 2` using the following  `docker cp  deploy <container_id>:/`

Now when i navigate into the container created in step 2 and try to run the simple console application i get the following error

`qemu-x86_64: Could not open '/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1': No such file or directory`.  i also followed the steps given here [dotnet publish --self-contained option on Linux container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073116/dotnet-publish-self-contained-option-on-linux-container) but no success.  not sure what is going wrong.  this is what my .csproj looks like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora I ran:

```
sudo dnf provides /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
```

which says the package I need is

```
musl-libc-1.2.3-1.fc36.x86_64
```

Command to find package name may be different depending on what distro you are running.

Comment: but i'm using an image recommended by Microsoft, shouldn't it work by default without me having to mess around with the installed packages.

Comment: I don't have that library on my Linux system. It's not standard.